# I want to click on a div and goes on a new page with a different image depending on the link (dynamically)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i have this div

```
<div class="mark1">
        <img src="images/mark1.png">            
    </div>
<div class="mark2">
        <img src="images/mark1.png">
</div>
```

and i run this jquery when he clicks on the div

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

$('.mark1').on({
     'click': function(){
        window.location.href='reservations.html';
     }
 });
 
 $('.mark2').on({
    'click': function(){
       window.location.href='reservations.html';
    }
});
```

how can i add a jquery that gets a different image at the top according to the mark a user clicks (dynamically at the same page)

Comment: I think you should use **queryString** for this.

Comment: as @AjeetEppakayala suggested: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22607328/3995126

Comment: and how can i use it here with the image i want?

Answer (score 0):

You can use one javascript function and call this function in different div. I think this solution is easiest for you.

```
<div class="mark1" onclick="openwindow();">
    <img src="images/mark1.png">            
</div>
<div class="mark2" onclick="openwindow();">
    <img src="images/mark1.png">
</div>

function openwindow(){
  window.location.href='reservations.html';
}
```

Comment: i already do this but i want to have a particullar image at the top according to the mark he clicks

Comment: you can use onclick function in particullar image.