# Getting woocommerce product attributes url to display on product page as an image

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm currently trying to develop my wordpress store using wordpress and woocommerce and I've run into a problem I can't seem to find the answer.

So i have added a attribute called 'images' on all my products which shows a link to an external url as seen in the screenshot, is there somehow I can grab this url and put it into my code? Example `<img src="ATTRIBUTE IMAGES LINK HERE" />` so i can display this image on the products page? I've look around but I'm not the best with php so was hoping someone here might be able to help me.

[image: 1]

Comment: Maybe a Javascript function?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22607150/getting-the-url-parameters-inside-the-html-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
<img src="<?php echo esc_attr($product->get_attribute('images')) ?>">
```

Should do the trick.

You may have to add

```php
global $product;
```

before, if it's not there already.

Comment: wow thank you for the quick reply, worked perfect!