# I don't want the user to get the file directly from the url

Tags: javascript, html, server

For example:

```
url(`https://example.com/file.exe`)
```

If a user visits this website directly, the user will be redirected to `https://example.com/getfile.html`
but allow the user to get the file if the user gets the file from `<a>` tag of `https://example.com/getfile.html`

Comment: We don't know what your backend language is. With PHP you could make a difference between GET calls en POST calls.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by removing href attribute in anchor tag and adding onclick function to the anchor tag. In onclick function send some parameter in url to get that value in your html page when user visits the page.

[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17863986/is-there-a-way-to-pass-javascript-variables-in-url) to know how to send parameter in url.

[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22607150/getting-the-url-parameters-inside-the-html-page) to know how to get post parameter from the url .

Still you have any confusion, you can comment your questions to this answer.

If you are using php you can get post parameter from url in a single line of code by using $_REQUEST["your post parameter name"];

I am adding a simple example for this to achieve with simple html and jquery.

with jquery document.referrer method on document ready(when user opens a page), you can get the previous url of user visited. like bellow example. for this you need to include jquery in your page by following line inserting in your page.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log(document.referrer);
if(document.referrer == "your url") {
    your code to allow user if comes from the url you mentioned //user will get download button or you can write direct download option;
} else {
     window.location = "some url";   //you can redirect user to specific url
}
});
<script>
```

Comment: What is the technology you are using in backend except html, javascript

Comment: i have updated answer with jquery code. please check once

Comment: Yes I know, but I think this only can use in html, but I want it to affect my file.exe

Comment: You can acheive this only with jquery. With html you cannot get the users previous url or if he comes direct

Comment: I don't know what languge can I use to do that in the file.

Comment: its your choice. if you want to use you can use jquery or if you wanna use php you can use. To run php you need a apache server. for jquery you dont need any software to install.

Comment: I see. but if I want to add script to the file, what languge should I use?

Comment: you can use jquery/javascript to show file or redirect user to home page